# Does mysql SUBSTRING_INDEX() work with joint in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to use SUBSTRING_INDEX with join in codeigniter but it don't work

As below code how can I correct it?
I want to use this code to select two table of my database and joint on **In_no**

And **value** of **In_no** is difference:

value of in_no in table invoice_all is ISP1501-n+ and IP1501-n+

and **value** of **in_no** in table **add_val** is n+

**I got empty pages when I load view on codeigniter**

```
<?php
    class Report_m extends MY_Model{
        public function __construct(){
            parent::__construct();
        }

        public function select_in_completed(){
            $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->from('add_val');
            $this->db->join('invoice_all','SUBSTRING_INDEX(invoice_all.in_no,'-', -1) = add_val.in_no');
            $this->query = $this->db->get();
            if($this->query->num_rows()>0){
                return $this->query->result();
            }
        }
    }
```

However When I used **$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);** the Codeigniter show me like below images

[image]
Please help.

Comment: How doesnt it work? whats the error? whats it doing instead of working?

Comment: How can I get thee result?

Comment: add profiler in your class . $this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE); it will show you your original whole query to mysql tables at bottom of html page. Then try to debug. is there actually return any row?

Comment: I get this messages

SELECT *
FROM (`dbfinan_add_val`)
JOIN `dbfinan_invoice_all` ON 0